# Java Version for PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I need to use PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle in Eclipse for a Development project. Is Java 6 enough to use these tools? or I need java 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything should work for

```
1.5>=Java<1.8
```

### Findbugs

> FindBugs requires JRE (or JDK) 1.5.0 or later to run.  However, it can
>   analyze programs compiled for any version of Java, from 1.0 to 1.7.
>   Some classfiles compiled for Java 1.8 give FindBugs problems, the next
>   major release of FindBugs will handle Java 1.8 classfiles.

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/

### Checkstyle

> Added Java 7 support to the grammar. Thanks to Dinesh Bolkensteyn for
>   patch #3403265
>   http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html

### PMD

> •2011-11-04 PMD 4.3 (download):  ◦Add support for Java 7 grammer -
>   thanks to Dinesh Bolkensteyn and SonarSource

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/

Comment: *Everything should work for 1.5>Java<1.8* - Java 1.5 will work, too. Maybe it should be `>=`. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Java 6 is enough (Even 5 will work).

Answer (score 0):

Notice latest [PMD](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/BUILDING.md) requires Java 7/8

> running PMD only requires Java 7 (or Java 8 for Apex and the Designer).